# Using ajax to get javascript value in another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a button that counts clicks and i want that final value to get stored in my database but I'm having a hard time getting that value.
I have one page where i have the counter and i tried using ajax to get it to the other page, here's the code.

```
var clicks = 0;

function hello(){
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
}

$.ajax({
    url: 'conta.php',
    data: {'score' : clicks},
    type: 'POST'
});
```

And in conta.php:

```
echo $_POST['score'];
```

The problem is when the timer runs out and it goes to conta.php there is an Undefined index: score  error.
Would really welcome suggestions if possible.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['score']` is the value you posted to the URL in the response to **that** POST request.

If you want to get the data in a *different* request then you'll need to store it somewhere (such as a database) and then read it from wherever you stored it when you get the request that you want to use to display it.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but how do you store the final value into the database?
Can i make an mysql query using a javascript variable?
thanks

Comment: You've used JavaScript to make an HTTP request to a PHP program. PHP can talk to the database. (Client side code can't)

Comment: INSERT $_POST["score"] into your database using a SQL statement in you php script. Google PHP PDO Insert Data Into Database if you don't know how

Comment: Do you mean something like this:

$adddesafiado = "Update desafio  set clicksdesafiado = '".$_POST['score']."' where desafiado= '".$usn."' and idd= '".$iddd."'" ;
                                            $arraaddesafiado= mysqli_query($con,$adddesafiado);


Because i've tried it and it still gives me the  Undefined index: score  error

Comment: @FilipeRosa — You have to read the data from the database and not from $_POST when you load the new page after the timer runs out. (Also, that is vulnerable to SQL injection).